# Fill each spinner row with two values from database

Tags: android, database, spinner

I have a spinner currently being filled with one column (name) from a database. I would like to change this to have each spinner row displaying the name, a space and an Id from the same table. This is the code I am using at the moment, I am not sure how to map multiple rows in the "from" array into the same textview in the "to" array.

```
    Cursor c = db.fetchAllUsers();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
    String[] from = new String[]{"name"};
    // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    // create simple cursor adapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
      new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    // get reference to our spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder` with a custom `ViewBinder` that does what you wish. To elaborate, you can simply ignore `columnIndex` in your implementation of `setViewValue` and use the given `Cursor` to populate the given `View` however you wish.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#setViewBinder(android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder)